# Создание формата ячеек JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

```
    public class KadrPress extends JFrame{
    public KadrPress() throws HeadlessException {
        super("Кадровая работа");
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(lineMenu(),"North");
        this.add(osnTabPane(),"Center");
        this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    //Создание меню
    private JMenuBar lineMenu()
    {
        //Меню файл
        JMenuBar lineMenu=new JMenuBar();
        //Меню Файл
        JMenu filemenu=new JMenu("Файл");
        JMenuItem newFile=new JMenuItem("Создать");
        JMenuItem openFile=new JMenuItem("Открыть");
        JMenuItem saveFile=new JMenuItem("Сохранить");
        filemenu.add(newFile);
        filemenu.add(openFile);
        filemenu.add(saveFile);
        filemenu.addSeparator();
        filemenu.add(new ExitAction());
        lineMenu.add(filemenu);
        return lineMenu;
    }
    //Создание основной панели с вкладками
    private JTabbedPane osnTabPane()
    {
        JTabbedPane osnTabPane=new JTabbedPane();
        osnTabPane.addTab("Общие сведения",osnovSvedeniyaJLabel());
        osnTabPane.addTab("Лист 2",new JPanel());
        return osnTabPane;
    }
    //Панель основные сведения
    private JPanel osnovSvedeniyaJLabel()
    {
        JPanel osnovSvedeniyaJLabel=new JPanel();
        osnovSvedeniyaJLabel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        osnovSvedeniyaJLabel.add(levayaJTable());
        osnovSvedeniyaJLabel.add(new JLabel("2"));
        return osnovSvedeniyaJLabel;
    }
    //Модель основной таблицы
    private JTable levayaJTable ()
    {
        String[]dannie=new String[]{
                "Фамилия","Имя","Отчество","Личный номер","Число, месяц, год рождения",
                "Место рождения (согласно паспорта)","Серия и номер паспорта","Дата выдачи","Кем выдан",
                "Код подразделения","Серия и номер удост. личности (Военного билета)","Дата выдачи(ВБ)",
                "Кем выдано","ИНН"
        };
        JTable levayaJTable=new JTable(new OsnovTable(dannie));
        levayaJTable.setRowHeight(20);
        levayaJTable.setOpaque(false);
        levayaJTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1)
                .setCellRenderer(new MaskTableCellRenderer());

        return levayaJTable;
    }
    //Модель основной таблицы
    private class OsnovTable extends AbstractTableModel
    {
        String[]dannie;
        HashMap<String,String>data=new HashMap<>();
        public OsnovTable(String[]dannie) {
            this.dannie=dannie;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return dannie.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex==0)return dannie[rowIndex];
            if (columnIndex==1) return data.get(dannie[rowIndex]);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            if (columnIndex==0)return false;
            if (columnIndex==1)return true;
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            data.put(dannie[rowIndex], (String) aValue);
        }
    }
    //Создание маски таблицы
    private class MaskTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
    {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            if (table.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).equals("Число, месяц, год рождения")){
            //if (dannie[row].equals("Число, месяц, год рождения")){
                try {
                    MaskFormatter dateMask=new MaskFormatter("##.##.####");
                    dateMask.setPlaceholderCharacter('0');
                    return new JFormattedTextField(dateMask);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        }
    }


    //Команда выхода из приложения
    class ExitAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        public ExitAction() {
            putValue(NAME,"Выход");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new KadrPress();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, имеется модель таблицы приведенная выше. На вход поступает массив

```
String[]dannie=new String[]{
                "Фамилия","Имя","Отчество","Число, месяц, год рождения",
                "Место рождения (согласно паспорта)","Серия и номер паспорта","Дата выдачи","Кем выдан",
                "Код подразделения","Серия и номер удост. личности (Военного билета)","Дата выдачи(ВБ)",
                "Кем выдано","ИНН"
        };
        JTable levayaJTable=new JTable(new OsnovTable(dannie));
```

Необходимо следующее:
1. Для строки "серия и номер паспорта" задать MaskFormatter типа ("#### ######")
2.Для строки "Число, месяц, год рождения" задать MaskFormatter типа ("##.##.####")
Подскажите каким образом лучше реализовать данную задачу. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно это поможет:

```
    MaskFormatter maskFormatter1 = new MaskFormatter("+ (###) ### ####");
    MaskFormatter maskFormatter2 = new MaskFormatter("### ### ####");
    levayaJTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(
            new DefaultCellEditor(new JFormattedTextField(maskFormatter1)) {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
            JFormattedTextField c = (JFormattedTextField) super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
            if (row %2 ==0){
                maskFormatter2.uninstall();
                maskFormatter1.install(c);
            }
            else {
                maskFormatter1.uninstall();
                maskFormatter2.install(c);
            }
            return c;
        }
    });
```

Comment: В вопрос включил код полностью. Необходимо исключить неверный ввод, однако получается изменить только первоначальное отображение таблицы.

Comment: ну тогда Вам надо cellEditor определять, однако менять его в каждой строке будет не удобно, ответ можно удалять ?

Comment: А можно пример?

Comment: @Александр изменил ответ